# Why amd I getting warnings from Log4J 1.2.17?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-webflow

Why amd I getting warnings from Log4J 1.2.17?  I am trying to use log4j in my java project but I keep getting the following warnings. can someone please tell me why?

THE WARNINGS:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 87
log4j:WARN Document root element "log4j:configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 87
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

MY log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j = "http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug = "false">
    <appender name = "FILE" class = "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name = "File" value = "test.log"/>
        <param name = "MaxFileSize" value = "5MB"/>
        <param name = "MaxBackupIndex" value = "50"/>
        <layout class = "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name = "ConversionPattern" value = "[%d{dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss:sss z}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <category name = "org.uftwf">
        <priority value = "debug"/>
    </category>

    <!-- 
    <category name = "org.apache.catalina">
        <priority value = "error"/>
    </category>


    <category name = "org.hibernate">
        <priority value = "debug"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate.SQL"> 
        <priority value="TRACE"/>  
    </category> 

    <category name="org.hibernate.type"> 
         <priority  value="TRACE"/> 
     </category> 

     -->

    <root>
        <priority value = "warn"/>
        <appender-ref ref = "console"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I know its only a warning but I want to learn why I am getting them and also stop them from coming.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a `<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">` before your `<log4j:configuration`.

Comment: @AKC No, according to: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html the DOCTYPE is not used anymore.